# Inaccessible "SHADOW" directory in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

While trying to figure out what takes up storage space on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system, I came upon a directory called `SHADOW` inside the main Windows directory that I cannot access in any way. When trying to view its contents or properties, I am only notified that I do not have the permissions to view it, "even as an administrator" (which I am). I am advised to try to take ownership to access it, and while that proceeds without error, it will afterwards continue to tell me I do not have permission, and the owner "can not be shown".

The directory name is shown in blue in Explorer, which I believe signifies that the contents are compressed.

- What is this directory for?
- How can I get any kind of access to it?

This is a virtual machine, by the way (hosted with an external provider, so I don't know what kind of hypervisor it runs on, in case that might be of any relevance).

Comment: Was this machine used for Linux? User info is stored in SHADOW. However, I'd be suspicious of that folder in Windows. Even with Windows Shadow Copy operating, I've not seen such a folder. If it's feasible to shut down the server and boot from USB, e.g., Linux, I'd look at that folder's contents.

Comment: No, this is the only operating system that was ever installed on it. It's a virtual machine hosted with an external service provider, but fully managed by ourselves.

Comment: The above advice of using Linux Live is a way of looking into the contents of the folder.